# Db2 mainframe commands

Tags: command, db2, mainframe

I am naive in mainframe and my question would sound silly. However, I want to know where do we write or issue db2 commands,say diplay database command. Under which option do we issue these commands. Also, how do we find which database is active? This question sounds weird, however, the same was asked to me.

Comment: I suggest you request training from your employer.  While you may be able to obtain answers to your questions, you are missing a number of basic concepts and this is not the appropriate forum in which to acquire them.

Comment: Also, please define 'mainframe' - is the specific system listed in the definition the one you actually meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM has an [Info Center article](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.admin/src/tpc/db2z_whereentercommands.htm) about where you can issue DB2 commands on the Mainframe. However, if you're not familiar with the Mainframe in general, it may not be all that useful to you.

As @cschneid recommends, you may want to ask around in your employer if there is any expertise on the subject. Otherwise, you need to get some training from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful DB2 tool on the mainframe called SPUFI which can execute SQL statements.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_executesqlspufi.html

There's also a DB2 Admin Tool as well.